# RegEx find and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have 18 MB data script file  where i have to find string like this replace 
with empty string in NotePad++

```
(1,
(2,
(3,
....
(312456
```

total # of records are 312456. start string will have "(" and end string will be first comma(,) in the file. I tried something like this `^([\d*]$`
I am no way near to the right expression

Here is sample data

```
VALUES (1, 258, N'somedataaa', N'000010000001', N'', N'', N'', N'', getdate())
```

it should be after replacement like this

```
VALUES (258, N'somedataaa', N'000010000001', N'', N'', N'', N'', getdate())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
^\(\d+,$
```

For find and nothing for the replace?

EDIT: As per update, try using this:

```
(?<=\()\d+,\s*
```

And replace with nothing.

Comment: @Thiruvalluvar Your sample data is different from the one you had initially in your question...? How should the sample data become now?

Comment: @Thiruvalluvar It wasn't really clear, but now it is. See update.